# iOS 8 custom table view cell selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, row, selection

I have some problems with my custom cells. I created New custom TableViewCell with its own xib file. The table loads and data is being populated in all the cells - that is all ok. But when i run my app in devices and simulators with iOS 8 and above the select method never fires. This problem does not happen when i run the application on devices and simulators with iOS 7.x. Here is the code for the CustomCell.m file

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
// Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Here is mu CustomCell.h file

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *directionImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *distanceLbl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *pathDescriptionLbl;
```

And here is the code from the ViewController

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"row selected");
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [steps.stepsData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"directionsCell";
DirectionsTableViewCell *cell = (DirectionsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    NSString *cellNib = [Utilities getDirectionCellNib];
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellNib owner:self options:nil];
    cell =  [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}

if(indexPath.row == 0 || (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)){
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:242.0/255.0 green:242.0/255.0 blue:242.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}else{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
cell.directionImage.image = nil;
cell.distanceLbl.text = @"";
cell.pathDescriptionLbl.text = @"";

if(indexPath.row != 0){
    UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 1)];
    separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0/255.0 green:200.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
}
cell.pathDescriptionLbl.text = @"main text here";
Step *stp = [steps.stepsData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *txtDetails = @"Details text here";
cell.distanceLbl.text = @"Distance here";
return cell;
}
```

What i find weird here is that the row selection works perfectly on iOS 7 but NOT on iOS 8. The data is being populated in both cases.

Am i doing something wrong here or am i missing something.
Thanks in advance for the help folks.

Comment: Strange that it won't work on iOS 8. Check to make sure that your `delegate` and `data source` are both set for your `UITableView`

Comment: They are both set in the viewDidLoad method

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.directionsList.dataSource = self;
    self.directionsList.delegate = self;
}

Comment: Hmm. So it's `didSelectRow` that isn't firing or `setSelected:`?

Comment: it is the didSelectRow method

Comment: @Zolnoor is right. You have not made clear exactly what is not happening that you expect to be happening. So what is not happening? Does the cell turn blue when selected? Does `-setSelected:animated:` get called? Does `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` get called? Please be more specific.

Comment: The cell DOES NOT turn blue when selected, the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: DOES NOT get called. That is the method i need in order to redirect the user to another ViewController. I can scroll and search the table, but i cannot select any rows when i run in iOS 8